# Is there some new conflict between newtxtext and \verb?

Tags: verbatim, newtx

I have LaTeX file that ran a couple of months ago but now generates a fatal error.  Here is an MWE getting the same error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
 \verb"a"   
\end{document}
```

This is minimal: Removing either the `\usepackage{newtxtext}` line or the `\verb` makes it work to produce a PDF.  But the file as I put it here produces:

```
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/newtx/ntx-ec-tlf.enc}
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file t1xtt): Font t1xtt at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have no idea what would fix this.

Comment: Run in the miktex console (user mode) the task "refresh font map files".

Comment: My MiKTeX console opens in admin mode and I do not see any option to switch to user mode. But in admin mode, the  task "refresh font map files" worked.  My original file now compiles as it used to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has been solved by performing software maintenance.